# Change Foreign Key name in django migration

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I'm looking to change the name of a foreign key from `uuid` to `uuid_erp`.

To do this i can run a migration as follows:

```py
migrations.RunSQL('''
    ALTER TABLE result_suppliers 
    RENAME COLUMN uuid TO uuid_erp;
''')
```

By doing this i essentially want to do the migration for django, and that it does nothing when running `makemigrations`.

However when i do run `python manage.py makemigrations` i see that django is trying to create the column uuid_erp (which has already been created).  this gives the message:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'uuid_erp' to resultsuppliers without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

From the [makemigrations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#makemigrations) I see that django:

> Creates new migrations based on the changes detected to your models.

This doesn't give a huge insight into how the changes are detected.

My question is two fold:

- How does makemigrations decide that there is a migration to make? (and can i get it to skip a certain operation)
- How can I perform this operation ?

NB. If I use makemigrations instead of the custom rename command, django deletes and recreates a uuid_erp and the existing info in uuid is lost.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use case for [SeparateDatabaseAndState](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#separatedatabaseandstate).  There is a great example of how to do this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/writing-migrations/#changing-a-manytomanyfield-to-use-a-through-model).